# Sum of big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Big O when adding together different routines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007723/big-o-when-adding-together-different-routines)

What does `O(n) + O(log(n))` reduce to? My guess is `O(n)` but can not give a rigorous reasoning.

I understand `O(n) + O(1)` should reduce to `O(n)` since `O(1)` is just a constant.

Comment: Shouldn't you do your own homework?

Comment: @Yuck Sorry I did not find out that post.. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well since `O( f(n) ) + O( g(n) ) = O ( f(n) + g(n) )` We are simply trying to calculate an `f(n)` such that `f(n) > n + log(n)`

Since as n grows sufficiently `log(n) < n` we can say that `f(n) > 2n > n + log(n)`

Therefore `O(f(n)) = O(2n) = O(n)`

In a more general sense, `O( f(n) ) + O( g(n) ) = O( f(n) )` if `c*f(n)>g(n)` for some constant c. Why? Because in this case `f(n)` will "dominate" our algorithm and dictate its time complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Order is always reduced to higher order terms. I can give you intuitive reasoning. Suppose you have `O(n + n^2)`. Then which part would play more important role in run time? n or n^2. Obviously n^2. Because where there n^2 you won't notice effect of n when n is increased or decreased.

As example,

```
let n = 100, then n^2 = 10000
means n is 0.99% and n^2 is 99.01% of total running time.
What would you consider for runtime?
if n is increased then this difference is clearer.
```

I think you understand now,

Answer (score 1):

the answer is O(n). O(log n) is less than O(n). 
so their addition sums the maximum value that is O(n).